# How to test if a string is a vim command?

Tags: vimscript, functions

Hopefully, the solution is efficient if it exists.

A solution that tests if it is a vim builtin command suffices.

---

**EDIT** To answer @Xiong Chiamiov comment, here is what I do in my `.vimrc`:
basically **get input, then run command, capture and put**.

```
nnoremap <M-x> :<C-u>call GetInputCommandThenCaptureAndPut()<CR>

func! GetInput()    " https://stackoverflow.com/a/15274117/3625404
    call inputsave()
    let cmd = input('ex-command to execute: ')
    call inputrestore()
    return cmd
endfunc
func! GetInputCommandThenCaptureAndPut()
    " cmdline keymap works, eg, <C-k> to get last input, <C-f> to open edit window, <C-r> insert register.
    let cmd = GetInput()
    if cmd =~ '^\s*!'   " eg, '!ls', '!ll', redraw needed.
        exec 'r'.cmd
        redraw!
    elseif cmd =~ '^ [[.a-zA-z0-9].*'    " one space before shell command, add '!', then run and read.
        exec 'r!' cmd
    elseif cmd =~ '^    [[.a-zA-z0-9].*'  " leading '<Tab>' key, execute shell command, witout capture.
        exec '!' cmd
    else
        if strlen(cmd) == 1     " customized shortcut
            if cmd == 's'
                let cmd = 'scr'
            elseif cmd == 'k' || cmd == 'm'   " :k is alias of :mark
                let cmd = 'marks'
            endif
        elseif cmd =~ '^\s*''\(\w*\)''\?\s*$'   " option start with single quote, closing one optional.
            let cmd = 'set '. substitute(cmd, '^\s*''\(\w*\)''\?\s*$', '\1', '').'?'
            " let cmd = 'set '.cmd.'?'
        endif
        let command = matchstr(cmd, '\w\+')
        if exists(':'.command)
            call PutAfterCapture(cmd)
        else    " not ex command, try run and read shell command.
            exec 'r!'.cmd
            redraw!
        endif
    endif
endfunc
```

The `PutAfterCapture()` is as below:

```
func! Capture(excmd) abort  " from tpope's scriptease.vim
try
    redir => out
    exe 'silent! '.a:excmd
finally
    redir END
endtry
return out
endfunc

func! PutAfterCapture(command)
    if a:command =~ '^\s*$'
        return
    endif
    let oldpos = getpos('.')
    silent! let @c = Capture(a:command)
    call setpos('.', oldpos)
    put c
    call setpos('.', oldpos)
endfunc!

command! -bar -nargs=+ Icapture call PutAfterCapture(<q-args>)
```

**The workflow is type `<M-x>`, then type the cmd to run and capture.**  `<C-f>` is handy for longer input here, `<C-r>` works too.

Examples:

- `ls` -- list of open buffers
- `<Space>ls` or `!ls`  -- list of files in current directory
- `s` -- vim files being sourced
- `m` -- marks
- `<Tab>bc` -- use `bc` calculator interactively

Comment: Why?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Xiong Chiamiov See [my answer below](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13881/10254),  basically **get input, then run command, capture and put**.

Comment: Question locked following [this meta question](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/1841)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I you only need to know if it is a built-in command, you can use

```
exists(':yourstring')
```

See [`:h exists()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#exists()) for more details.